# TypeError: employee.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a form where the user can add input fields with a click event. I built a handler where the user can add multiple text fields and insert multiple names that will be sent to a database.
I was successful in adding input fields, [following this link](https://www.cluemediator.com/add-or-remove-input-fields-dynamically-with-reactjs)
I ran into a challenge where I could not submit the string data to the database. I solved this issue by pushing the value of the input field to the employee array.
My problem: when I add a second text field a get the error `employee.push is not a function.`

My question how can I solve this? For example, if the user wants to add two names by adding two text fields to input the names, how can I fix the code to send the names to the DB?

I know I have to map the result of the original map to do this, but I am not sure how to insert the target value from the handler event in the employee array (where the name strings are stored in the DB).

It got the code to only work once, when you add one name and submit, the name is sent to the database, however when more than one name is added (even before the submit) the code breaks.

I am using context and useState hooks:

AddAccountsContxt.js

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const AddAccountsContxt = createContext();

export const AddAccountsContxtProvider = (props) => {
  const [company, setCompany] = useState("");
  const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);
  const [employee, setEmployee] = useState([]);

  const addAccountHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setDetails([...details, employee]);
    console.log('employee', details)
    details.push({employee:employee});
    axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:5000/insert-form",
      data: {
        company: company,
        address: address,
        phone: phone,
        // employee: employee,
        details: details
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <AddAccountsContxt.Provider
        value={[
          company,
          setCompany,
          address,
          setAddress,
          phone,
          setPhone,
          employee,
          setEmployee,
          details,
          addAccountHandler,
        ]}
      >
        {props.children}
      </AddAccountsContxt.Provider>
    </>
  );
};
```

EmployeeName.js

```
import { React, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Row } from "react-bootstrap";
    
const EmployeeName = ({ employee, details, setEmployee}) => {
const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([{ employee: "" }]);

  const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...inputList]; 
    list[index][name] = value;
    setInputList(list);
    console.log("value", value);

    //below code implamented to push name string to employee array
    setEmployee(...employee, value);
    if (value) {
      employee.push({value:value});
    }
  };

  const handleRemoveClick = (index) => {
    const list = [...inputList];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setInputList(list);
  };

  const AddInputField = () => {
    setInputList([...inputList, { employee: "" }]);
  };


  return (
    <>
        <Button onClick={AddInputField}>
          click here to add company employees
        </Button>
      {inputList.length > 0 &&
        inputList.map((x, i) => {
          return (
            <Row key={i}>
              <Col sm={11}>
                <Form.Group>
                  <Form.Control
                    placeholder="Add Employee Name"
                    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
                    value={x.employee}
                    name="employee"
                    type="text"
                  />
                </Form.Group>
              </Col>
              
              <Col>
                {inputList.length - 1 === i ? (
                  <Button
                    onClick={AddInputField}         
                  > Add
                  </Button>
                ) : (
                  <Button onClick={() => handleRemoveClick(i)}>Remove</Button>
                )}
              </Col>
            </Row>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
};

export default EmployeeName;
```

Comment: How do you use the `<EmployeeName>` component? How properties are passed to it? From what I can see in the code posted, it expects the `employee` prop to be an array. Make sure you're passing an array.

Comment: employee={employee}
              setEmployee={setEmployee}
              details={details}
            />

Answer (score 0):

In React, state should be treated as immutable, so you shouldn't even be pushing to elements to `employee`, but rather pass in an entirely new array to `setEmployee`.

When you call `setEmployee(...employee, value)` in `handleInputChange` of `EmployeeName`, you set employee as the first element of its previous value, which makes it no longer an array on its next render, causing the TypeError when attempting to push. Instead put a useEffect with a dependency on the inputList so that when the inputList is set, map the inputs to an employee.

```
const EmployeeName = ({ setEmployee }) => {
    const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([{ employee: '' }]);
    useEffect(() => setEmployee(inputList.map((input) => ({ value: input.employee }))), [inputList]);

    const handleInputChange = (event, index) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        const list = [...inputList]; 
        list[index][name] = value;
        setInputList(list);
    };

    const handleRemoveClick = (index) => setInputList(inputList.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
    const AddInputField = () => setInputList([...inputList, { employee: '' }]);

    return (
        <>
            <Button onClick={AddInputField}>click here to add company employees</Button>
            {inputList.map((input, index) => (
                <Row key={index}>
                    <Col sm={11}>
                        <Form.Group>
                            <Form.Control
                                placeholder='Add Employee Name'
                                onChange={(event) => handleInputChange(event, index)}
                                value={input.employee}
                                name='employee'
                                type='text'
                            />
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Col>

                    <Col>
                        {inputList.length - 1 === index ? (
                            <Button onClick={AddInputField}> Add</Button>
                        ) : (
                            <Button onClick={() => handleRemoveClick(index)}>Remove</Button>
                        )}
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            ))}
        </>
    );
};
```

This also applies to all other states like `detail` which should be rewritten to just `setDetail([...details, {employee}]` instead of attempting to push to state.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, when I apply your changes I am no longer sending the employee name to the database, the push error is solved but now the data is not being pushed in the employees array

Comment: @Julie I just edited my answer, try and see if that works for you

Comment: Thank you again for your help, the answer did not work for me, I am trying concat but I am only getting the first letter of the second input, however, one the first input I am sending to DB successfully.